# Replacing interval with requestAnimationFrame for Swiper carousel progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although the following code below that adds a progress bar to 'JS Swiper' has worked well in the past, I've noticed with a new project I'm working on I have been getting flickers in transitions which I have traced to the progress bar.

I would like to replace '''interval''' with '''requestAnimationFrame''' as from understanding it will make the progress bar run at a higher FPS which I'm hoping will resolve the issue with the flickering, but having tried to implement this not only does the progress bar stop on interaction, it increases in speed with each pass.

Please could you take a look at the code and point me the right direction - thanks-you...

```
var duration = 3;
var interval = 5;
var progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress');

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    }
});

// Main Progress Bar Function

var percentTime, step, tick;

function startProgressbar() {
    resetProgressbar();
    percentTime = 0;
    isPaused = false;
    tick = window.setInterval(increase, interval);
}

function increase() {
    if (!isPaused) {
        step = duration * 1000 / interval;
        percentTime += 100 / step;
        progressBar.style.width = percentTime + "%";
        if (percentTime >= 100) {
            mySwiper.slideNext();
            startProgressbar();
        }
    }
}

function resetProgressbar() {
    progressBar.style.width = 0 + "%";
    clearTimeout(tick);
}

startProgressbar();

// Pause Control

var isPaused = false;

// Pause Carousel when it's Hovered Over

$('.swiper-container, .carousel-progress').mouseenter(function() {
    isPaused = true; // (Change 'true' to 'false' if not required)
});

$('.swiper-container, .carousel-progress').mouseleave(function() {
    isPaused = false;
});

// Reset Progress Bar on Slide Change

mySwiper.on('slideChange', function() {
    startProgressbar();
    isPaused = true; // (Change 'true' to 'false' if not required)
});
```

Comment: I've just created a pen here: https://codepen.io/mikeyjn/pen/gOmqLjp
If someone could please help me with this I would br very gratful as I've been playing around for hours on this now and just can't figure it out - thanks